# Построение гистограммы относительных частот в R

Tags: r, гистограммы

(Задание учебное, но найти что-то похожее не сумел)
Дан интервал от 15 до 55. На нем существует 299 значений. Интервал разбит на 12 равных частей. Число значений для каждой части заданы вектором 5 10 25 45 55 60 46 28 15 5 3 2. То есть, длина интервала 55-15=40, в нем всего 12 отрезков, длина каждого отрезка d=40/12. На первом отрезке - 5 значений, на второй - 10, и так далее. 
Эмпирическая частота для каждого отрезка: на первом отрезке x1=5/299, на втором x2=10/299, итд
Относительная частота для каждого отрезка: на первом отрезке x1/d, на втором x2/d, итд
Подскажите, как построить такую гистограмму в R?

Comment: например, с помощью [функции `hist()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html)

Answer (score 0):

Подготовка данных

```r
# минимльное значение интервала
min_value <- 15
# максимальное значение интервала
max_value <- 55
# значение частот в каждом отрезке
abs_freqs <- c(5L, 10L, 25L, 45L, 55L, 60L, 46L, 28L, 15L, 5L, 3L, 2L)
# относительные частоты
rel_freqs = abs_freqs / sum(abs_freqs)
# границы отрезка
breaks <- seq(from = min_value, to = max_value, length.out = length(abs_freqs) + 1)
# названия для меток отрезков в формате [начало,конец)
labs <- sprintf("[%.3f,%.3f)", breaks[-length(breaks)], breaks[-1])
labs[length(labs)] <- gsub("\\)$", "]", labs[length(labs)])
labs
#> [1] "[15.000,18.333)" "[18.333,21.667)" "[21.667,25.000)" "[25.000,28.333)" "[28.333,31.667)" "[31.667,35.000)"
#> [7] "[35.000,38.333)" "[38.333,41.667)" "[41.667,45.000)" "[45.000,48.333)" "[48.333,51.667)" "[51.667,55.000]"
# формируем таблицу данных
DF <- data.frame(
  abs_freqs = abs_freqs,
  rel_freqs = rel_freqs,
  labs = labs
)
```

Построение графика встроенными средствами R:

```r
barplot(abs_freqs ~ labs, data = DF, xlab = "", ylab = "Абсолютная частота")
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Построение графика средствами пакета ggplot2:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = labs, y = abs_freqs)) + 
  geom_col(color = "black", fill = "white") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Абсолютная частота") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Аналогично для относительных частот:

```r
barplot(rel_freqs ~ labs, data = DF, xlab = "", ylab = "Относительная частота")
```

```r
ggplot(DF, aes(x = labs, y = abs_freqs)) + 
  geom_col(color = "black", fill = "white") +
  labs(x = "", y = "Абсолютная частота") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```